# AEM: reading a value from a node in java which is value of a multifield

Tags: java, content-management-system, aem

I am reading a set of node in java. each node is of one country. each node has  property "country" and for some countries like US has "states" property node too. This "states" is part of a multifield hence each item has one state which is all together in one node something like this:

```
country = "US"
, states = [{"statename":"District of Columbia"}, {"statename":"Rhode Island"},{"statename":"South Dakota"}]
```

I want to populate them as a json in the page through a servlet call like this:

http://localhost:4502/bin/utilservlet.json

```
{
    country: "India"
    {
        statename:"Delhi", 
        statename:"Punjab",
        statename:"Haryana"
    }
} 

{
     country: "Turkey"
}
```

following is my code:

```
while (nodeItr.hasNext()) {
                    Node cNode = nodeItr.nextNode();
                    if (cNode.hasProperty("country")) {
                        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
                        jsonData.put("country", childNode.getProperty("countryname").getValue().getString());
                        jsonArray.put(jsonData);
                        if (cNode.hasProperty("states")) {
// This should display array of all states as an when it is encountered.
LOG.info(childNode.getProperty("states").getValue().getString());
```

Following happens:
1. I get all the country list except the first country for which states property is exits.
2. No other country where statelist is there, is displayed.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is Node your custom class, if yes please provide it's code as well.

Comment: Node is javax.jcr.Node class;

Comment: So I am trying to understand, are u able to read all the data through Node ( I mean all countries and their corresponding states) and unable to write it to JSON format. Or Are u not even able to read it?

Comment: I am able to read all the countries which are not populated through a  multifield, however at the same node nevel "states" is populated through  a multifield value. So it stores as a string array inside the node in crxde its:


country type(String)  India
states:   type(String[]) { statename:"Delhi", statename:"Punjab", statename:"Haryana" }

then next node, for the countries which doesn't have states, they don't have the "states" properties

Comment: so, it checks for the if condition for the state in encounters for the first country which has it, prints it, never checks the next country states. Also all country which has states as a property subsequently is omitted. 

I think I am doing something wrong while reading the property for a string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if (cNode.hasProperty("states")) {
    Property statesProperty = cNode.getProperty("states");
    if (statesProperty.isMultiple()) {
        Value[] statesValues = states.getValues();
        for (Value stateValue : stateValues) {
            LOG.info(stateValue.getString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you also please answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685126/aem-getting-states-matching-country-from-another-node

Comment: I would like to remind people that using org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource, org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap interfaces instead of low-level javax.jcr.Node, javax.jcr.Property.  They are easier to use, don't throw exceptions, and lead to simpler, more maintainable code.